# Is there any possibility to create checked and unchecked exceptions in the dart?

Tags: java, dart, exception, runtime

In Java we can make exceptions of both types. Checked and unchecked exceptions.
Checked Exception we need to extend our class with Exception class and for unchecked exception we need to extend class with Runtime Exception. The code will not compile until we handle checked exception and IDE gives safety to handle checked exception before compilation
while runtime exceptions has no safety. Does dart support this feature?

Comment: There's no built-in way to have checked exceptions.  Also see https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/45884

Comment: I would recommend using a package like [oxidized](https://pub.dev/packages/oxidized) and to return values from methods that might normally possibly return null (use the `Option` class) or throw an error (use the `Result` class) in order to force you to confront those possibilities before you can access the returned values.